# I want to find files with no suffix and delete them. How do you do this?

Tags: linux

I would like to find and delete all files from a folder and its subfolders with a certain property: that they have no three letter suffix.  How do you do this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR; (which is a really bad idea when automatically deleting stuff)

`find . ! -name "*.???" -type f -max-depth 1 -delete`

---

Properly explained and tested:

Step 0: Setting up the test environment:

```
mkdir test
cd test
touch test1
touch test1.bar
touch test1.foo
touch test1.baz
touch test1.bazar
```

Step 1: Find all files which have a three letter extension:

```
find . -name "*.???" -type f -print
./test1.bar
./test1.baz
./test1.foo
```

Step 2: Inverting the selection

```
find . ! -name "*.???" -type f -print
./test1
./test1.bazar
```

Step 3: Replace the `-print` with `-delete`.

If you do not want to dive into subdirectories add a `-max-depth=1`

Comment: I think that the maxdepth option is supposed to go before any other options (it won't cause any actual problems, but will throw up an error, at least with GNU find). Also, isn't it `-maxdepth 1`, or is this one of those 'multiple valid syntax' things?

Comment: Probably one dash. At least according to [http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find), FreeBSD (which shows `-maxdepth n`) and an older Ubuntu (`-maxdepth levels`). Now correct in the post. Thanks for noticing.

Comment: I added subdirs and tried with both maxdepth as first argument, as last argument and with it somewhere in the middle. All results were the same, so the order does not matter. At least not on my test system.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have bash version 4+ (you can check with `bash --version`)

```
shopt -s extglob  ##  turn on extended globbing
rm -- !(*.???)
```

For recursiveness:

```
shopt -s extglob globstar
rm -- **/!(*.???)
```

In general I would recommend putting this line in your .bashrc, since extended globbing and globstar are really useful:

```
shopt -s extglob globstar
```

Answer (score 1):

You might try with `find`.

Use this to show them first to make sure you get the right files:

```
find . -type f ! -name "*.???"
```

When you are sure you want to delete them you can use:

```
find . -type f ! -name "*.???" -print0 | xargs -0 rm -rfv
```

or if you prefer the `-exec` way:

```
find . -type f ! -name "*.???" -exec rm -rfv {} +
```

note: The `{} +` only works from a certain version and up (check the manual `man find` under `-exec` second paragraph. Otherwise you could use `-exec -rfv  {} \;` but that gives a lot of overhead, executing `rm` for each file.

Use this in the correct folder. Otherwise replace `.` with the foldername.

Comment: Oh, while I am in nitpick mode: the third command will execute a rm command for each file. Overhead++.  You can minimise that with `{} +` (see the second paragraph about `-exec ` in `man find`).

Comment: @Hennes Thanks for the catch on the `-print0`. I knew about the overhead of `-exec`. That's why i prefer `xargs`. Didn't know about the `{} +` though. Changed it in my answer. Thanks.

Comment: I failed to read the {} + part myself until a few months ago. Having two paragraphs describing the exec option caused me to only read the first one.  Right now it is rather fresh in my mind though. :)

Comment: @Hennes And in my Fedora 3 (i know... OLD) setup it doesn't work. On my Centos it does work. So it's only possible to use `{} +` from a certain version and up. Always check the manual ;)